# WebRTC in Android WebView using NextRTC Spring Signaling Server

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, webview, webrtc

I am new to webRTC. I am trying to make a skype like calling app in android using webRTC. I am using [NextRTC](https://github.com/mslosarz/nextrtc-videochat-with-rest) in Spring Boot as an example server. I have the server on http. I have hacked the android by using an example page ([room.html](https://github.com/mslosarz/nextrtc-videochat-with-rest/blob/master/src/main/webapp/room.html)) from the [nextRTC](https://github.com/mslosarz/nextrtc-videochat-with-rest) example. Everything was fine in the login and all but when I try to connect with the websocket from the webView it gives this error.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.2:8090/signaling' failed:
>   Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

In [room.html](https://github.com/mslosarz/nextrtc-videochat-with-rest/blob/master/src/main/webapp/room.html) the url can be found at line 30, from where I am getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NextRTC has WebSecurityConfig.java file which actually redirects the unauthentic URLs to login page and that redirection caused this error. I have omitted that code and finally everything is working.